# django not recognizing my index.html page, stuck on the install worked

Tags: python, django

I have an index.html page made and also referenced in views.py and urls.py. For some reason, the home page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ only shows the install worked default page.

Am I calling it wrong? I followed the installation step-by-step and it's not working at all

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
   
<p>index</>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you register your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @Corralien - yes, i have 'proteindata.apps.ProteindataConfig', inside my INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: And do you include your views in your `urls.py` project? (not `urls.py` of your app)

Comment: @Corralien yes, from . import views is at the top

Comment: No, this comes from your `urls.py` application not `urls.py` project (where your `settings.py` is stored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `urls.py` project, you have to include your `urls.py` from your app. Something like:

myproject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('proteindata.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I see what ur saying now, thank you!

Comment: I did path('', include('proteindata.urls')), and it's working, thanks a lot